# C# legit ProcessKill on my ConsoleApplication

Tags: c#, process, antivirus

I am using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` for killing my application process and it works well, But it causes my application to be detected as malware or get detected by suspicious behavior by *Symantec Endpoint Protection*, and i am assured that this is the cause of detection because every time i add this, my app will be removed by AV.

**Q**: I wanted to know is there any tricky or legit way to get current Process and Kill it ?

**Note:** I also asked from security experts and read some articles in Internet and both said this way of killing process is the cause of detection.

**Note 2:** The application will compress files and upload them to FtpServer.

Comment: What about just returning from the main thread?

Comment: If the application is compressing files and uploading them _why_ do you need to kill anything? It should just run and exit.

Comment: I am executing the application from windows shell, don't know why but the process will remain

Comment: Then something is wrong with your app :P

Comment: @JoachimOlsson you mean using `async await` and put `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()` within it ?

Comment: Have you tried using `Environment.Exit(0)` instead? (Though, as BugFinder already pointed out, there should be no need for that, so you should also debug your application to find out why it is not exiting properly)

Comment: @bassfader it will exit properly on normal use. but its process will remain when executing it through windows shell.

Comment: No, with exiting from the main thread I meant that your program has an entry point, the thread that calls that entry point is your main thread. If you return from that function call your program will return control to the OS and all memory and threads still executing will eventually be cleaned up. If your process remains even after returning from main in shell that sounds like a bug one which you should create a minimal reproducable example for which we can verify it with. This is unlikely though the problem is more likely to be within your code than something which has been tested and shipped

Comment: Thanks to all of ya. The problem was the zipping library. i changed it to sharpziplib and now TheApplication process will be killed through Windows Shell and so there is no need for a Code to kill process. But DotNetZip is absolutely better than SharpZipLib and i had to change it because of a simple AV problem.